# Recreating CentOS environment with Vagrant

Tags: linux, centos, puppet, vagrant

I have a Vagrant and CentOS related question. I'm trying to replicate a CentOS server which uses WHM/cPanel for hosting. Each site on the server is hosted in `/home/$user/`. This means with Vagrant I need to have a synced folder which is something like:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "~/my-local-folder", "/home"
```

Replicating this environment with Vagrant becomes an issue as the vagrant user (used for accessing the vagrant box) is stored inside the `/home` directory. This means that the process of syncing the folders removes the vagrant user (unless the vagrant directory already exists within my-local-folder).

I've found a way of recreating the vagrant user (including its ssh keys) as part of provisioning the server with puppet. I basically add back in the vagrant folder and create the .ssh keys but this feels wrong.

Is there another way I should be approaching this? Hosting the files on the Vagrant box in any other location is not an option as the aim is to replicate the box as closely as possible. It occurs to me that creating the vagrant user outside of the home directory would solve this entirely but i've not been able to find out if this is even possible.

Comment: In your bootstrap script, can't you do something like "mv /home/vagrant /var/vagrant/home ; sed -ei .bak 's/\/home\/vagrant/\/var\/vagrant\/home/g /etc/passwd" prior to syncing the home directories?

Comment: this wouldn't work as this would happen after the vagrant home sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the vagrant user is created at the time that the Vagrant box is created. In my case, as with a lot of people I assume, i'm using a pre-built CentOS box from http://www.vagrantbox.es/. This box creates the vagrant user, and defines the location of the vagrant user's home directory - e.g. `/home/vagrant` - this means to solve my issue I need to create my own CentOS box with the vagrant user using an alternate home location.